# Referencing a vendor js file directly from erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to get rid of the asset pipeline altogether. 
As part of this move I need to get rid of the `application.js` file under `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

I have erb files that I want to specifically require my vendor files there, for example:

Instead of this line in `application.js`:

```
// = require jquery-2.2.3.js
```

I want to add something like this to `application.html.erb`:

```
<script src="vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-2.2.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This produces a 404 Error. How can I still do that?

If that matters, I have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in my `config/application.rb`

Comment: Use `javascript_include_tag 'jquery-2.2.3.js'`  withing your `head` element of `application.html.erb`.

Comment: Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-2.2.3.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Comment: Remove the sprockets gem from Gemfile. And then I would use NGINX to deliver the assets directly. It's admittedly inelegant, but this is the consequence of trying to workaround something so fundamental in Rails.